# For each row, count the number of dates that were within 12 months of each other?

Tags: python, date, datetime, dataframe

I wish to iterate through each column and check if the next date is within 12 months of the previous date.

For instance, here is an example. Dates have been sorted.

```
row_id|date_1    |date_2     |date_3     |date_4     |date_5    |count
   1   2006-07-28 2006-08-18  2007-01-02  2009-01-28  2011-02-03  3
   2   2000-07-21 2002-02-18  2004-05-02  2009-01-28  2011-02-03  0
```

Comment: Show your own effort and code trying to solve the problem (as properly formatted text in the question). If you get stuck at a specific issue, you can ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the count that you have in your sample output is incorrect. Here's what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

>>>df
   row_id     date_1     date_2     date_3     date_4     date_5
0       1 2006-07-28 2006-08-18 2007-01-02 2009-01-28 2011-02-03
1       2 2000-07-21 2002-02-18 2004-05-02 2009-01-28 2011-02-03

df.set_index('row_id', inplace=True)
df['count'] = df.diff(axis=1).lt(pd.Timedelta('1Y').sum(axis=1)

>>>df
           date_1     date_2     date_3     date_4     date_5  count
row_id
1      2006-07-28 2006-08-18 2007-01-02 2009-01-28 2011-02-03      2
2      2000-07-21 2002-02-18 2004-05-02 2009-01-28 2011-02-03      0
```

The count for *row_id* 1 should be 2 and not 3: 1. (*date_2* - *date_1*) and 2. (*date_3* - *date_2*)